# How to fix footer?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, footer

I have four panels and currently, I want to fit the panel under the third panel only.

```
footerRoot: {
        /* textAlign: "center", */
        backgroundColor: theme.palette[0],
        bottom: 0,
        padding: "10px 10px 0px 10px"
}
```

I have many screens and for now, the footer shows perfectly at the bottom for only three screens while for the rest, the footer shows up abruptly in the middle of the page. How do I alter the code to push it to the bottom of the page on every screen?
Note: I want to avoid position: absolute.

Comment: Please provide more infomation like `html` code, some result image.

Comment: You can add `position:fixed` to make footer at bottom fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this code helps, as it defines the `body` `height` to `100%` no matter what the content inside it is and pushing the `footer` contained element to the bottom of the `body` of the web page and to stretch it across the `body` `width` `left: 0` and `right: 0` would serve the purpose.

```css
body{
  min-height: 100%;
}
.footer{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">Footer Content goes here</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your  doesn't take full height of the document.
Add this to the top of your css

```
html {
   height : 100%;
}
body {
   min-height: 100%;
}
```

that should do the trick. If it doesn't show little more of your code so we could pin the issue.